# AWT Draw Floating-Point Rect

Tags: java, canvas, awt

In my AWT canvas, I want to draw a rectangle at coordinate (0.5, 0.5). Unfortunately, the `fillRect()` method only accepts integers. I am forced to cast my floating-point variables to get it to run at all.

True: Because the canvas coordinates are in pixels, the 0.5 doesn't matter because you can't have half of a pixel. However, when I scale everything by 50, I can easily tell the the rectangle is not where I want it.

In case you are planning on answering with "why do you want to scale everything up in the first place?", I want to convert my physics engine coordinates to canvas coordinates. For example: entity at (1, 0) in world coordinates should be (400, 300) in canvas coordinates on a canvas of size 600x600. It is not CRUCIAL, but I would very much appreciate a way to make a floating-point rectangle. Or a better way to convert the coordinates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pixels don't have fractions, it's simply not possible.  The `Shape` API support which brought fractional parameters was designed for high resolution printing purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a [`java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html). Which allow you to draw at decimal coordinates.

```
Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(.5, .5, 4, 6);
```

Creates a rectangle at coordinates of (.5, .5) and dimensions of (4, 6). You should draw this using [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html). Here's how to convert your `Graphics g` into a `Graphics2D` object then draw the rect:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
g2d.draw(rect);
```

Comment: While technically correct, you can't have a fraction of a pixel...just saying ;)

Comment: Course not, but it can be faked.

Comment: Works great, centered on the screen accurately enough for me!

Comment: I notice you are doing `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();` I have seen other code that does `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;` Do you know of any important difference between the two?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes you can, it is done all the time, it is called anti-aliasing.

Comment: @MikeNakis Except not all `Graphics` contexts are configured for anti-aliasing - and in fact, you're still only filling a single pixel, albeit with a alpha color

Comment: @MikeNakis `Graphics`, in Swing, is a shared context, shared amongst the other components been painted, modifications of the context can spill onto other components which don't modify the context in the same way you did - which can lead to very unpleasant results.  `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();` simply allows you to copy the attributes of the current context, manipulate them without worrying about how they affect subsequent users.  Just remember, you also need to call `g2d.dispose()` when you're doing this, to free up any resources been used

Answer (score 1):

I've been "criticised" that my comment *"Pixels don't have fractions, it's simply not possible."* is not "accurate"

So, let's focus on a simple example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += 2) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += 2) {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, getHeight());
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + getWidth(), y);
                }
            }

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5);
            g2d.draw(rect);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

The above code produces something like...

[image: Solid Pixels]

So, by default, anti-aliasing is not enable in Swing.  So in the example above, the rectangle starts at `10x10` and is `11x11` pixels in size

If we modify the code to include (in my testing, this was done below the code that drew the grid and before the code which drew the rectangle)...

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

This produces...

[image: Fuzzy]

The rectangle still starts at `10x10`, but now has a "alpha" component extending beyond it's `10x10` at the size of 1 pixel, down it's right and bottom sides.

Sooo, my point is.  A pixel is AWLAYS `1x1`, you can't have a "fraction" of a pixel.  The amount of "fudge" factor you can generate, through things like anti-aliasing will also be dependent on the underlying platforms graphics/rendering workflows.

How ever, I agree with BitNinja, the Graphics 2D Shapes API is a more suitable API to use in almost all cases other the original API.